# YouTube IFrame API Error

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am having a problem loading the YouTube IFrame API.
I add the tag and YouTube loads their scripts, but when I call the constructor, I get an error.

```
player = YT.Player('vidPlayer', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: id,
    playerVars: {
        'rel': 0
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': playerReady,
        'onStateChange': playerStateChange
    }
});
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong there. When I call that constructor, it throws an error. This is what the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.G is not a function
qb @ www-widgetapi.js:24
P @ www-widgetapi.js:20
X @ www-widgetapi.js:31
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady @ script.js:55
(anonymous function) @ www-widgetapi.js:39
(anonymous function) @ www-widgetapi.js:39
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: As you haven't posted the whole code, take a look at my mini project: https://github.com/alibozorgkhan/minidj/blob/master/static/js/minidj.js. Maybe it helps you find out what the problem is.

Comment: @AliBZ The onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function and the script to add the player_api is the only thing inside the code, so what you see here is pretty much everything minus the tag script.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem. I notice that you, like me, over looked the `new` keyword in front of `YT.Player`.

`YT.Player` is a constructor function, so it won't work without the `new` keyword.

Comment: Yes back then I wasn't familiar with the concept of objects in JavaScript. Even now until you pointed it out I didn't know that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I having also the same problem.This works for me.I am using the YouTube iFrame API and then creating the object .Its works fine for me. 
Add the script in our file where you want to create the object.

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Then Add the div where iFrame is being loaded.

```
  <div id="iframe"></div>
```

Now the JavaScript to load the YouTube iFrame through YouTube API

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframe', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

function onPlayerReady() {
    console.log('onPlayerReady');
    player.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
    //your code after change the state
}
```

)};

The onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function getting called Automatically by YouTube iframe API when it gets loaded.